# Which manifest key is used to hold the text in the "Details" tab?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

If you select an Add-on in about:addons you can see a "Details" tab that holds text describing the Add-on. Here is an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYMvz.png

**Which manifest key is used to hold this text?** (Note, it's not the description key as that is used for "A short description of the extension".

UPDATE: So it seems this "Details" text is pulled from The Developer Hub page for the Add-on in question (the "Describe Add-on" section"). Question: I am only updating this text, not anything in the code of the Add-on. How do I "publish" this change so that it shows up in my browser in the Add-on page in about:addons? I don't see any way to do that in the Developer Hub.

Or do I need to upload a new version of the Add-on, even though I am not changing anything in the code?

Comment: It's copied from addons.mozilla.org page.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. In the Add-ons developer hub in the "Describe Add-on" section there's a "Description" box. I think this is what you were referring to. If I now update that box with a description do I need to republish and re-install my (personal) Add-on, or will the Description text update in my browser automatically?